# Проблема с настройкой WCF в сети

Tags: сеть, c#, клиент-сервер, хост, wcf

Написал клиент-серверное приложение с использованием WCF. На localhost все работает без проблем, но не могу настроить его, чтобы оно работало в реальной сети на нескольких компах.
Вот конфиг сервера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Service.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint
                address="/Service"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="Service.IService" />
    <endpoint
                address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Base"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|    \Base.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

А вот конфиг клиента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Service" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="IService"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="pavel\Павел" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

На клиенте адрес будет не localhost, а IP сервера в сети.

+какой-то вы странный порт выбрали, я бы не советовал.

---

А если добавить к конфигу сервера, что будет?

```
<system.serviceModel>
....
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
...
<system.serviceModel>
```

И endpoint изменить

```
<endpoint   bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
            address="/Service"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="Service.IService" />
```

И может ещё в клиенте изменить

```
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
     <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
     </security>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

---

Ещё можно попробовать удалить Identity секцию из конфига клиента.

Либо изменить endpoint конфига сервера так

```
<endpoint address="/Service"
             binding="wsHttpBinding"
             contract="Service.IService" >
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="pavel\Павел" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

---

Наверное, самое правильно решение

Биндинг клиента поменять на

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
     <security mode="Message">
         <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
     </security>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Если и заработает, то будет работать только внути вашего домена

Это потому, что wsHttpBinding юзает windows security проверку по умолчанию. Возможно, вам стоит использовать basicHttpBinding

---

Советую к прочтению

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788755.aspx

Comment: @Veikedo Сорри, я прописывал, там IP-адрес компа с сервером, но все равно не получается. Вылетает ошибка "подлинность вызывающего пользователя не была проверена службой"

Comment: @Павел Воевода, обновил